# Visit visa got rejected in 2018. How long should I wait to apply for a new one (Work permit)?

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, refusal, uk-visitor-visa

I applied for a visit visa in 2018 and got rejected - not sure why. Now I am trying to apply for a work permit visa and want to check whether the previously rejected visa will affect the work permit application. It's close to 5 years and if I apply, will that affect my visa?

Can someone help me get more details on whether I can apply or not?

I am from India and applied for a visitor's visa to London. The visa was refused, stating that I don’t have a property and the funds are not sufficient.

Comment: The rules around eg eligibility and suitability for a visit visa are typically very different to those for a work visa. Unless your previous refusal was for a reason such as deception, it’s probably unlikely that it would affect a work visa application. But to answer we need to know more details

Comment: Why was your visit visa refused?

Comment: Visit visa was refused stating that i doesnt have a property and the funds are not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

The rules around eligibility and suitability for a visit visa are typically very different to those for a work visa. For the former, being able to demonstrate a compelling reason why you will leave the UK at the end of the proposed visit and that you have sufficient funds for your trip, is critical. A work visa however, inherently involves immigrant intent and the rules around funds/salary levels etc are generally clear.

IMHO therefore, a visitor visa refusal under Immigration Rule V4.2 from five years ago will have little/no bearing on a work visa application, assuming you meet the criteria for the latter. You must however disclose the refusal in your work visa application; if you do not, your application will be refused https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1160299/Suitability_false_representations.pdf.